# Set theory - Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = [x: x∈R, |x|<1]$ ; $B = [x: x∈R, |x-1| \geq 1]$ and $A \cup B = R-D$, then the set $D$ is ?
Need help with explanation, Thanks.

Comment: $A$ is the interval $(-1,1)$ and $B$ is the interval $(-\infty, 0] \cup [2, \infty)$. Now see if you can proceed from here.

Comment: With terminology like ASAP you are breaking your own windows. Also you should show some own effort to solve this.

Comment: Well, don't judge me. I am new to maths, a solo learner. And I already tried before posting here, and I guess that's the purpose of StackExchange " to get help when you need it ". Although I agree with that ASAP thing. I edited the question.

Comment: Sadly, there are no online classes on Set theory on Khan academy or any other education websites which can help beginers to learn it.

Comment: Hint Use DeMorgan's rule

Comment: @ManvendraSingh Interpret my comment as an effort to bring you in the position of a student who will get the help he needs. I am a big fan of: "thou shalt not judge".

Comment: @drhab Ofcourse sir, I will try my best from now on.Thank you for your kind suggestion. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer notation $E^c$ stands for $\mathbb R-E$. This for subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Based on $D^c=A\cup B$ you can conclude that $D=A^c\cap B^c$ by applying [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). If you are not yet familiar with them then I advice you to become familiar with them ASAP :).

It is clear that $A^c=(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$ and $B^c=(0,2)$ so it remains to find their intersection. Can you do that?

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I solved it. Also I see what you did here ('ASAP') :)